# Opening 2 windows with one link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone have an idea why the following code doesn't work (Google Chrome in OSX Lion):

I have a link:

```
<a id="testlink" href="">TEST</a>
```

And I want it to open 2 new windows using jQuery:

```
$testlink = $("#testlink");

var urlList = "http://www.cnn.com,http://www.foxnews.com"

function openLinks() { 
    $.each( urlList.split( "," ), 

    function( index, item ) 
    { window.open( item, "_blank" ) }
    ); 

}

$($testlink).click(openLinks);
```

Also, just using 2 times window.open doesn't work.

I have been looking for hours how to do this so I hope someone will be able to answer.

I know this code works but only half because it does open the first URL and just skips the second.

Maybe I should also tell what I'm trying to do here. I want to find a way that gives the user the possibility to download something and then gets a thank you page. From here I was gonna make my way into a straight through download link + thank you page in new window. So I don't want the user to have to click on something else to get a thank you :)

Thanks in advance, 
Caroline

Comment: Please replace `$($testdownload).click(openLinks);` with `$('#testdownload').click(openLinks);` and check. It seems wrong

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to be more adequate I changed 'testdownload' to 'testlink' not for anyone to get confused. But I did what you said here and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your code runs perfectly fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/HGWNw/

Comment: The code seems ok but you might have trouble opening multiple Windows in Chrome because of Pop-up blocking.

Answer (score 0):

This is working try this

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$testlink = $("#testlink");

var urlList = "http://www.cnn.com,http://www.foxnews.com"

function openLinks() { 
    $.each( urlList.split( "," ), 

    function( index, item ) 
    { window.open( item, "_blank" ) }
    ); 

}

$($testlink).click(openLinks);
})
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/zXd4D/

Comment: Lol okay, I've been breaking my head over something that apparently works in other browsers. Just tested in Firefox and then Merguez is right. 


Pranav and Krunal, your codes seem to work as well as what I had before apparently. Anyone has an idea why Google Chrome only gets the first link? Because I need it to work in all browsers of course.

Comment: I can see chrome is blocking popup..
That's why it's happening

Comment: So what you're saying is Chrome blocks popups by default? But if I use a Facebook share button for instance, this does work in Chrome and as far as I know that also uses a popup.

Comment: Chrome opens first popup..
As i know you require the user to click again some button to trigger the popup ..
SO you need another click to open another popup

Comment: Maybe I should tell what I'm trying to do here. I want to find a way that gives the user the possibility to download something and then gets a thank you page. From here I was gonna make my way into a straight through download link + thank you page in new window. So I don't want the user to have to click on something else to get a thank you :)

Comment: ohkk.
Wait i am implementing ma logic.. As i complete i will edit my answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll be waiting patiently

Comment: ooops... Couldn't do that..
Also searched for it...
Der is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running perfectly fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/HGWNw/

I'ld advice to change this line

```
$($testlink).click(openLinks);
```

to this

```
$testlink.click(openLinks);
```

Since `$testlink` is already a jQuery object. It won't break your code, but its just more readable.

Your problem is maybe due to your browser settings about blocking popups. In my Chrome, the first link is opened in a new tab, the second in a new window.

Comment: only works full in Firefox, IE and Google Chrome only make the first window appear and Safari does nothing... So if I understand well people will either see one window, all or none of them. Would it be possible to look for a valid solution, apart of browser settings anyway or this rather impossible?

Comment: @user3098836 It works in Chrome, it just opens the first link in a new tab instead of a window.

Comment: I only get to see the cnn.com link and indeed in a new tab. To me it doesn't matter if it gets opened in a new tab or window, but the other link doesn't appear to me in any way, not in a new window or tab.

Comment: Have you checked the popup options for your site?

Comment: How would I be able to set those for my <b>site</b>? I'm testing locally, plus it fully works in Firefox.